# Почему Owl Carousel не подключается?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, owl-carousel

Почему Owl Carousel не работает?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop: true,
    margin: 10,
    nav: true,
    responsive: {
      0: {
        items: 1
      },
      600: {
        items: 3
      },
      1000: {
        items: 5
      }
    }
  })
  
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.theme.default.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>

<div class="owl-carousel">
  <div class="item"><h4>1</h4></div>
  <div class="item"><h4>2</h4></div>
  <div class="item"><h4>3</h4></div>
  <div class="item"><h4>4</h4></div>
  <div class="item"><h4>5</h4></div>
  <div class="item"><h4>6</h4></div>
  <div class="item"><h4>7</h4></div>
  <div class="item"><h4>8</h4></div>
  <div class="item"><h4>9</h4></div>
  <div class="item"><h4>10</h4></div>
  <div class="item"><h4>11</h4></div>
  <div class="item"><h4>12</h4></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Скорей всего вы подключили стиль не той версии. У вас скрипты версии **2.2.1**, а стиль `owl.carousel.css` **1.3.3**

`https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.css`

А надо было:

`https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.carousel.css`

Рабочий пример: https://jsfiddle.net/hhnq8a26/